# Alternative of arch_fast_hash in Linux kernel v3.19 and above

Tags: linux, kernel, hashing

To find the hash value of a given buffer, I used `arch_fast_hash` function present in Linux kernel v3.16 declared in `include/linux/hash.h` and defined in `linux/lib/hash.c`.

But in Linux kernel v3.19, that function is gone. Few new function and macros are there but without proper documentation.

Can any body please help me with a proper hashing technique or what's the alternative of `arch_fast_hash` in v3.19.

And also is there any faster alternative to hash?

***Links***

[include/linux/hash.h in Linux Kernel v3.16](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/hash.h?v=3.16)
[include/linux/hash.h in Linux Kernel v3.19](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/hash.h?v=3.19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#include <linux/jhash.h>
```

and use this function:

```
/* 
* jhash - hash an arbitrary key
* @k: sequence of bytes as key
* @length: the length of the key
* @initval: the previous hash, or an arbitray value
* 
* The generic version, hashes an arbitrary sequence of bytes. 
* No alignment or length assumptions are made about the input key.
* Returns the hash value of the key. The result depends on endianness.
*/

u32 jhash(const void *key, u32 length, u32 initval);
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain this?  Thanks.

Comment: edited the answer, hopefully it is more clear now

Comment: Thanks for adding the information but, at least for me, it doesn't really explain how to use this (it's probably obvious to someone who already knows the answer, but for beginners, not so much).  Maybe if you included an example?  Being pretty unfamiliar with this stuff, it isn't clear what is a literal term vs. a placeholder for an input value.

Comment: function provides 32 bit hash value for memory block staring at key and length long, with given initialization value. It is the same idea as in arch_fast_hash function asked in the question

Comment: OK, maybe this is one of those questions that's really only useful to someone familiar with the subject.  Sometimes these can be useful to educate beginners if more detailed usage info is included.  BTW, I didn't downvote, but it isn't clear whether someone else was also looking for more detail or just didn't like your answer.  Anyway, thanks for trying to improve it (and welcome to Super User).